# ADO.NET SqlDataAdapter how to clear an error condition

Tags: ado.net, error-handling

Let's say you invoke the update method of the SQlDataAdapter:

```
        MyDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;
        if (MyDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Count > 0)
         {
             MySqlAdapter.Update(DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.Table);
         }
```

and your user happens to have left a required column NULL, so the back-end complains about it, and your catch block traps the "cannot be null" sql exception.  How do you clear the error state so that ADO.NET doesn't keep raising the same error again and again, even when the user supplies the required value? What object's method should be invoked, or what property should be changed, to put the adapter back into a state where the update can occur, as long as the missing value is supplied?

This doesn't seem to be enough:

```
        internal void OnRowUpdating(object sender, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred)
        { 
            e.Row.RowError = e.Errors.Message;
            e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user fills in the required value the "cannot be null" exception will go away. It's that easy, but then again I do the saving this way:

```
DataTable changes=MyDataSet.Tables[0].GetChanges();
if (changes!=null)
{
    MySqlAdapter.Update(changes);
    MyDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: I will consider the GetChanges method; but how/where are you handling errors?

Comment: any "cannot be null" exceptions will be thrown at MySqlAdapter.Update().  Catch the exceptions there and then you have to allow the users to then change the value to non-null and then run this code again with a Save button press or something.